# Chart.js Line graph legend yields error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on a line chart with the Chart.js library, I have a graph with multiple data sets that generate multiple lines on a graph. I want there to be a legend on the top which shows the color and the label of each of the datasets.

I looked at the example on the docs and it said to add

```
legend: {
   display: true
}
```

to the options. When I try this my graph no longer renders and I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Here is the code with the legend option:

```
    function renderChart(data, labels){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var dsets = [];
        var keys = Object.keys(data);
        console.log(data);
        for (i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
            dset = {
                label: keys[i],
                data: data[keys[i]],
                borderColor: '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16),
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            }
            dsets.push(dset);
        }
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: dsets
            },
            options: {
              legend: {display : true},
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Minutes'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: false,
                            labelString: 'Months'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

UPDATE: The issue was twofold: 1, I was not on the current version. 2, I was rendering the graph after a button push. It wants to render on page load, and then I used update function to render on the button push.

Comment: at which line code, the error is pointing to?

Comment: I added it to the end of the post.

Comment: @kingkyle, can you show what exactly line of code yields error? Not line number.

Comment: yep sorry, I added the function where the error occurs.

Comment: `labels` is an array. What is the type of `data`?

Comment: data is a dictionary or JSON Notice the loop trough data to create the dsets arrays. which would just be [10.5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].... etc.

Comment: @kingkyle, can you show `console.log(keys);?

Comment: This is console.log(keys);    ["Writer", "Editor", "Publisher", "QualityController"]

Comment: Can you show the line of code from `at ChartElement.draw (Chart.js:6178)` ?

Comment: This is line 6178: x: this.left + ((legendWidth - lineWidths[0]) / 2),  Which is part of                         cursor = {
      x: this.left + ((legendWidth - lineWidths[0]) / 2),
      y: this.top + labelOpts.padding,
      line: 0
     },

Comment: Ok, `lineWidths[0])` should be the problem. Can you check `console.log(lineWidths)`?

Comment: Im getting undefined? i just did console.log(lineWidths); at the top of the renderChart function.

Comment: Find where `lineWidths` should be added

Comment: Is this your variable or from library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206989/discussion-between-kingkyle-and-webprogrammer).

Comment: its from the library

Answer (score 1):

**Upd.4**

I have tasted it on my computed as static html-file. Can you create on your computer `index.html` and put to it this code?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>
        function renderChart(data, labels){
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var dsets = [];
            var keys = Object.keys(data);
            console.log(data);
            for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
                var dset = {
                    label: keys[i],
                    data: data[keys[i]],
                    borderColor: '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16),
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                }
                dsets.push(dset);
            }

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: dsets,
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }       

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        var data = {
            Writer: [10.5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            Editor: [16, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            Publisher: [0, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            QualityController: [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],        
        };
        var labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        renderChart(data, labels);      

        </script>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @kingkyle, what does show your `console.log(data);` and `console.log(labels);`?

Comment: So i added the outputs of the console logs. The data is correct as far as i can tell.

Comment: @kingkyle, I have made an update. Can you check it?